Why the rounded class is not working for <tr> 's border in a table?
<tr className="border border-[#D9DCED] rounded-t-[8px] ">
    <th className="font-[700] py-3 px-6">Title</th>
    <th className="font-[700] py-3 px-6 text-center cursor-pointer"> Price </th> 
</tr>

I am using tailwind css to round the border but it's not working .
I am expecting the border to get rounded as well but it's not working.

You are adding border to the row, did you try wrapping it in a <thead> element and adding a wrapper div
<div className="border border-[#D9DCED] rounded-t-[8px]">
  <table className="w-full">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th className="font-[700] py-3 px-6">Title</th>
        <th className="font-[700] py-3 px-6 text-center cursor-pointer"> Price </th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    ... 
  <table>
</div>

`



yes I tried that but it did not work

You can check the link from Justinas comment which has a lot of good information, i edited to provide a workaround, let me know if this helps
